# Doubling the lengths of a solid figure

Tags: volume, solid-geometry

Let K be a solid figure in $\mathbb{R^3}$, $\mu$ the 3-dimensional Lebesgue-measure and suppose we know, that $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(2*x_1,...,2*x_n) d\mu_n=\frac{1}{2^n}\int f(y_1,...,y_n)d\mu_n$ (what we get by substitution of $y_i=2x_i$ and the use of Fubini's theorem). When I now choose $\chi_{2K}$ to be the function that equals 1 for elements of 2K and 0 otherwise (where 2K is the extended figure) it follows:
$\mu_3(2K)=vol(2K)=2^3vol(K)=2^3\mu(2K)$.
Might someone give me a hint how I might get that $\chi_{2K}(y_1,...,y_3)=\chi_{K}(y_1,...,y_3)$?

Greetings

Rico

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is true is $\chi_{2K}(y_1,y_2,y_3)=\chi_K (x_1,x_2,x_3)$ where $y_i=2x_i$and this is what you need for the proof.

Comment: I have to think about that a little, thanks for your help.

Comment: Do we have for any solid figure that $2K:=\lbrace 2*x: x \in K \rbrace$ is the figure whose lengths have been doubled? Because up to now I only see that for the cartesian product.